# How to Access SelectedItem in one Page on a Separate Page

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have two datagrids separately on two pages, say a parentgrid on a parent-page and a childgrid on a child-page. how to access the selecteditem of parent-page to the child-page ?

when the both the datagrids are placed on the same page, the selecteditem works. but when I place the grids separately on each page, it doesn't work.

XAML for the ParentPage

```
<Grid.Datacontext>
 <local:MainViewModel/>
</Grid.Datacontext>
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHost, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"/>
```

codebehind for the ParentPage

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         ChildPage _page = new ChildPage();
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(_page);
    }
```

XAML for child page

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ChildDatagrid" Margin="12,104,81,266" ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"/>
```

MainViewModel

```
//Datacontext
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Persons = Person.GetPersons();
    }

    // for Person Datagrid
    private ObservableCollection<Person> personValues;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return personValues; }
        set { this.SetProperty<ObservableCollection<Person>>(ref this.personValues, value); }
    }

   //for the PersonDetails datagrid
    public ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> Details
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Selectedperson == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return this.LoadDetails(this.Selectedperson.PersonID);
        }

    }
    // method to load the persondetails data
    private ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> LoadDetails(int personID)
    {
        ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> details = new ObservableCollection<PersonDetails>();
        foreach (PersonDetails detail in PersonDetails.GetDetails().Where(item => item.PersonID == personID))
        {
            details.Add(detail);
        }
        return details;
    }

    // SelectedPerson Property
    private Person selectedPersonValue;
    public Person Selectedperson
    {
        get { return selectedPersonValue; }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty<Person>(ref this.selectedPersonValue, value);
            this.RaiseNotification("Details");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a ViewModel or Object, pass them into both pages and bind your grids to it. This way they will stay in sync.

Alternate option is to use and EventAggregator to sent messages between your pages.

If you're using WPF you should take a look into Prism. A lot of build-in functionality exists.

Comment: I already have a ViewModel where I have set up the property for selecteditem. and I tried to bind from my xaml. but it didn work ( it jus loads tha first datagrid items, it navigates but the datagrid on second page is empty)

Comment: what s about prism ? anyways thanks for the info. i will look over

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Post changed to reflect new information;

I've never used the NavigationService with WPF before, so I'm not 100% sure what is available to you, so apologies if I miss something.

However, if you move your `Details` Collection to your `Child` Form, and make it a standard property;

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> _Details;
public ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> Details {
    get { return _Details; }
    set {
            if (value.Equals(_Details) == false)
            {
                _Details = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Details");
            }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a reference to your `MainViewModel`, you can then navigate to your page using;

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ChildPage _page = new ChildPage();
    _page.Details = MainViewModel.LoadDetails(PersonID);
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(_page);
}
```

As a note, I don't like the idea of calling the Navigiate Service from the Code behind, as this makes the code messy and difficult to test.

Jesse Liberty has a nice post on using the MVVM Light Framework, and allowing the ViewModel to call the Navigate Service Directly;

http://jesseliberty.com/2012/01/17/calling-navigate-from-the-view-model/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am already following the MVVM pattern. pls see the marked as answer "http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/76ad5efe-0589-417d-9ffe-5c5911ffd520/#d884f0c8-a809-4358-b8e1-3b177ef3c48d". I have created one VieModel which sets all the binding.

Comment: Ahhh.. Ok... Can you post the XAML for your two DataGrids, and also your Properties in the ViewModel in your OP please?

Comment: Kindly have a look at my edited question. I have added. btw i use c#

Comment: I've reworked my original code... Hopefully that will help! :-D